# AVPlayer stops playing and doesn't resume again

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, avplayer

In my application I have to play audio files stored on a web server. I'm using `AVPlayer` for it. I have all the play/pause controls and all delegates and observers there which work perfectly fine. On playing small audio files everything works great.

When a long audio file is played it also starts playing fine but after some seconds the `AVPlayer` pauses the playing (most probably to buffer it). The issue is it doesn't resume on its own again. It keeps in a pause state and if I manually press the play button again it plays smoothly again.

I want to know why `AVPlayer` doesn't resume automatically and how can I manage to resume the audio again without user pressing the play button again? Thanks.

Comment: clear and simple :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942228/avplayer-item-buffer-empty/40171838#40171838

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it stops because the buffer is empty so it has to wait to load more video. After that you have to manually ask for start again. To solve the problem I followed these steps:

1) Detection: To detect when the player has stopped I use the KVO with the rate property of the value:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"rate"] )
    {

        if (self.player.rate == 0 && CMTimeGetSeconds(self.playerItem.duration) != CMTimeGetSeconds(self.playerItem.currentTime) && self.videoPlaying)
        {
            [self continuePlaying];
        }
      }
    }
```

This condition: `CMTimeGetSeconds(self.playerItem.duration) != CMTimeGetSeconds(self.playerItem.currentTime)` is to detect the difference between arriving at the end of the video or stopping in the middle

2) Wait for the video to load - If you continue playing directly you will not have enough buffer to continue playing without interruption. To know when to start you have to observe the value `playbackLikelytoKeepUp` from the playerItem (here I use a library to observe with blocks but I think it makes the point):

```
-(void)continuePlaying
 {

if (!self.playerItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp)
{
    self.loadingView.hidden = NO;
    __weak typeof(self) wSelf = self;
    self.playbackLikelyToKeepUpKVOToken = [self.playerItem addObserverForKeyPath:@keypath(_playerItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp) block:^(id obj, NSDictionary *change) {
        __strong typeof(self) sSelf = wSelf;
        if(sSelf)
        {
            if (sSelf.playerItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp)
            {
                [sSelf.playerItem removeObserverForKeyPath:@keypath(_playerItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp) token:self.playbackLikelyToKeepUpKVOToken];
                sSelf.playbackLikelyToKeepUpKVOToken = nil;
                [sSelf continuePlaying];
            }
                    }
    }];
}
```

And that's it! problem solved

Edit: By the way the library used is libextobjc

Comment: @weakify(self);
    self.playbackLikelyToKeepUpKVOToken shows error.

Comment: @weakify is a shortcut to make the pointer self to weak to avoid retain cicles in blocks. I changed it to make the code work as standard

Comment: I do not see any resume related API call, your codes just display a loading view, how to make the video playing again by codes?

Comment: I think you should compare playerItem.currentTime to loadedTimeRanges, not to playerItem.duration, because playerItem.duration only represent the full duraiton of playerItem.

Comment: what is self.videoPlaying suppose to be? this is the only answer on the topic on stack and it does not work with natural obj c

Comment: can we get a working sample or at least ur .h to know what some of these vars are ? or methods your calling do? like is continue playing just a a[vplayer play]; call?

Comment: guessing playbackLikelyToKeepUpKVOToken is a bool

 also this block continues to give me problems. maybe it shows my misunderstanding of these observers , but im sure others have been in my naive shoes and considering its the #1 answer on google it prob should be expressed in code a bit better.       self.playbackLikelyToKeepUpKVOToken = [self.playerItem addObserverForKeyPath:@keypath(_playerItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp) block:^(id obj, NSDictionary *change) {

Comment: This code does not solve any problem. It is hard to read, contains expressions and frameworks not easy to set up, and not popular enough to justify including in the answer, and also, the code does not do anything. 'continuePlaying' does not give any commands to avplayer, it just plays with the observers and recursively calls itself (why??). Bad answer.

Comment: Instead of the latest continueplaying, you should play the AVPlayer item

Answer (score 9):

I am working with video files, so there's more to my code than you need, but the following solution should pause the player when it hangs, then check every 0.5 second to see whether we've buffered enough to keep up. If so, it restarts the player. If the player hangs for more than 10 seconds without restarting, we stop the player and apologize to the user. This means you need the right observers in place. The code below is working pretty well for me.

*properties defined / init'd in a .h file or elsewhere:*

```
AVPlayer *player;  
int playerTryCount = -1; // this should get set to 0 when the AVPlayer starts playing
NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
```

*partial .m:*

```
- (AVPlayer *)initializePlayerFromURL:(NSURL *)movieURL {
  // create AVPlayer
  AVPlayerItem *videoItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:movieURL];
  AVPlayer *videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:videoItem];

  // add Observers
  [videoItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
  [self startNotificationObservers]; // see method below
  // I observe a bunch of other stuff, but this is all you need for this to work

  return videoPlayer;
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
  // check that all conditions for a stuck player have been met
  if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp"]) {
      if (self.player.currentItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp == NO &&
          CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE(self.player.currentTime, >, kCMTimeZero) && 
          CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE(self.player.currentTime, !=, self.player.currentItem.duration)) {

              // if so, post the playerHanging notification
              [self.notificationCenter postNotificationName:PlayerHangingNotification object:self.videoPlayer];
      }
  }
}

- (void)startNotificationObservers {
    [self.notificationCenter addObserver:self 
                                selector:@selector(playerContinue)
                                   name:PlayerContinueNotification
                                 object:nil];    

    [self.notificationCenter addObserver:self 
                                selector:@selector(playerHanging)
                                   name:PlayerHangingNotification
                                 object:nil];    
}

// playerHanging simply decides whether to wait 0.5 seconds or not
// if so, it pauses the player and sends a playerContinue notification
// if not, it puts us out of our misery
- (void)playerHanging {
    if (playerTryCount <= 10) {

      playerTryCount += 1;
      [self.player pause];
      // start an activity indicator / busy view
      [self.notificationCenter postNotificationName:PlayerContinueNotification object:self.player];

    } else { // this code shouldn't actually execute, but I include it as dummyproofing

      [self stopPlaying]; // a method where I clean up the AVPlayer,
                          // which is already paused

      // Here's where I'd put up an alertController or alertView
      // to say we're sorry but we just can't go on like this anymore
    }
}

// playerContinue does the actual waiting and restarting
- (void)playerContinue {
    if (CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE(self.player.currentTime, ==, self.player.currentItem.duration)) { // we've reached the end

      [self stopPlaying];

    } else if (playerTryCount  > 10) // stop trying

      [self stopPlaying];
      // put up "sorry" alert

    } else if (playerTryCount == 0) {

      return; // protects against a race condition

    } else if (self.player.currentItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp == YES) {

      // Here I stop/remove the activity indicator I put up in playerHanging
      playerTryCount = 0;
      [self.player play]; // continue from where we left off

    } else { // still hanging, not at end

        // create a 0.5-second delay to see if buffering catches up
        // then post another playerContinue notification to call this method again
        // in a manner that attempts to avoid any recursion or threading nightmares 
        playerTryCount += 1;
        double delayInSeconds = 0.5;
        dispatch_time_t executeTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
        dispatch_after(executeTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

          // test playerTryCount again to protect against changes that might have happened during the 0.5 second delay
          if (playerTryCount > 0) {
              if (playerTryCount <= 10) {
                [self.notificationCenter postNotificationName:PlayerContinueNotification object:self.videoPlayer];
              } else {
                [self stopPlaying];
                // put up "sorry" alert
              }
          }
        });
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks, your solution helped, I just had to make a few changes. Instead of observing key path "playbackLikelyToKeepUp", I used NSNotification "AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification" which informs my code when the player has stalled. And I used playerTryCount of 20 retries instead of 10 just to give it more time for users with shitty internet. The rest of the logic was great!

Answer (score 9):

Accepted answer gives a possible solution to the problem, but it lacks flexibility, also it's hard to read. Here's more flexible solution.

Add observers:

```
//_player is instance of AVPlayer
[_player.currentItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
[_player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rate" options:0 context:nil];
```

Handler:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath
                     ofObject:(id)object
                       change:(NSDictionary*)change
                      context:(void*)context {

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (_player.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            //Possibly show error message or attempt replay from tart
            //Description from the docs:
            //  Indicates that the player can no longer play AVPlayerItem instances because of an error. The error is described by
            //  the value of the player's error property.
        }
    }else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"rate"]) {
        if (_player.rate == 0 && //if player rate dropped to 0
                CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE(_player.currentItem.currentTime, >, kCMTimeZero) && //if video was started
                CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE(_player.currentItem.currentTime, <, _player.currentItem.duration) && //but not yet finished
                _isPlaying) { //instance variable to handle overall state (changed to YES when user triggers playback)
            [self handleStalled];
        }
    }
}
```

Magic:

```
-(void)handleStalled {
    NSLog(@"Handle stalled. Available: %lf", [self availableDuration]);

    if (_player.currentItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp || //
            [self availableDuration] - CMTimeGetSeconds(_player.currentItem.currentTime) > 10.0) {
        [_player play];
    } else {
        [self performSelector:@selector(handleStalled) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5]; //try again
    }
}
```

The "[self availableDuration]" is optional, but you can manually launch playback based on amount of video available. You can change how often the code checks whether enough video is buffered. If you decide to use the optional part, here's the method implementation:

```
- (NSTimeInterval) availableDuration
{
    NSArray *loadedTimeRanges = [[_player currentItem] loadedTimeRanges];
    CMTimeRange timeRange = [[loadedTimeRanges objectAtIndex:0] CMTimeRangeValue];
    Float64 startSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(timeRange.start);
    Float64 durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(timeRange.duration);
    NSTimeInterval result = startSeconds + durationSeconds;
    return result;
}
```

Don't forget the cleanup. Remove observers:

```
[_player.currentItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
[_player removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rate"];
```

And possible pending calls to handle stalled video:

```
[UIView cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(handleStalled) object:nil];
```

Comment: According to documentation - "**It is possible for playbackLikelyToKeepUp to indicate NO while the property playbackBufferFull indicates YES. In this event the playback buffer has reached capacity but there isn't the statistical data to support a prediction that playback is likely to keep up in the future. It is up to you to decide whether to continue media playback.**" I think it will also be important to check `playbackBufferFull`

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue.
I had some local files i wanted to play, configured the AVPlayer and called [player play], the player stops at frame 0 and wouldn't play anymore until i called play again manually.
The accepted answer was impossible for me to implement due to faulty explanation, then i just tried delaying the play and magically worked

```
[self performSelector:@selector(startVideo) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];

-(void)startVideo{
    [self.videoPlayer play];
}
```

For web videos i also had the problem, i solve it using wallace's answer.

When creating the AVPlayer add an observer:

```
[self.videoItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
// check that all conditions for a stuck player have been met
if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp"]) {
    if (self.videoPlayer.currentItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp == NO &&
        CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE(self.videoPlayer.currentTime, >, kCMTimeZero) &&
        CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE(self.videoPlayer.currentTime, !=, self.videoPlayer.currentItem.duration)) {
        NSLog(@"hanged");
        [self performSelector:@selector(startVideo) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
    }
}
```

}

Remember to remove observer before dismissing the view

```
[self.videoItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp"]
```

Answer (score 5):

I think use `AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification`  to detect the stalled is a better way.

Comment: I've been testing using this notification and it doesn't appear to fire every time. I switch the internet connection off -- wait until the buffer runs out -- it triggers -- switch internet back on -- wait until the player plays again -- wait 2 seconds (see A) -- switch internet off -- let the buffer run out -- doesn't trigger. A: The notification seems to only trigger again when I am waiting ~10 seconds between test cycles.

Answer (score 4):

First I observe for playback stalling

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerStalled),
    name: AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification, object: videoPlayer.currentItem)
```

Then I force playback continuation

```
func playerStalled(note: NSNotification) {
  let playerItem = note.object as! AVPlayerItem
  if let player = playerItem.valueForKey("player") as? AVPlayer{
    player.play()
  }
}
```

This is probably not the best way of doing it, but I'm using it until I find something better :)

Comment: According to Apple _The system may post this notification on a thread other than the one used to registered the observer._, thus `player.play()` is possibly called a different thread. Not sure if that is ok or not...

Answer (score 4):

I also ran into this issue as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62482826/4833705)

**I tested this answer below multiple times and it worked every time so far.**

Here is what I came up with for the Swift 5 version of [@wallace's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28371514/4833705).

1- instead of observing the keyPath `"playbackLikelyToKeepUp"` I use the `.AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled Notification` and inside there I check to see if the buffer is full or not via `if !playerItem.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp {...}`

2- instead of using his `PlayerHangingNotification` I use a function named `playerIsHanging()`

3- instead of using his `PlayerContinueNotification` I use a function named `checkPlayerTryCount()`

4- and inside `checkPlayerTryCount()` I do everything the same as his `(void)playerContinue` function except when I ran into `} else if playerTryCount == 0 {` nothing would happen. To avoid that I added 2 lines of code above the `return` statement

5- like @PranoyC suggested under @wallace's comments I set the `playerTryCount` to a max of `20` instead of `10`. I also set it as a class property `let playerTryCountMaxLimit = 20`

**You have to add/remove your activity indicator/spinner where the comment suggests to do so**

code:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerItemPlaybackStalled(_:)),
                                       name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled,
                                       object: playerItem)

@objc func playerItemPlaybackStalled(_ notification: Notification) {
// The system may post this notification on a thread other than the one used to registered the observer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1387661-avplayeritemplaybackstalled

    guard let playerItem = notification.object as? AVPlayerItem else { return }
    
    // playerItem.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp == false && if the player's current time is greater than zero && the player's current time is not equal to the player's duration
    if (!playerItem.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp) && (CMTimeCompare(playerItem.currentTime(), .zero) == 1) && (CMTimeCompare(playerItem.currentTime(), playerItem.duration) != 0) {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.playerIsHanging()
        }
    }
}

var playerTryCount = -1 // this should get set to 0 when the AVPlayer starts playing
let playerTryCountMaxLimit = 20

func playerIsHanging() {
    
    if playerTryCount <= playerTryCountMaxLimit {
        
        playerTryCount += 1

        // show spinner

        checkPlayerTryCount()

    } else {
        // show spinner, show alert, or possibly use player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem) to start over ***BE SURE TO RESET playerTryCount = 0 ***
        print("1.-----> PROBLEM")
    }
}

func checkPlayerTryCount() {
    
    guard let player = player, let playerItem = player.currentItem else { return }
    
    // if the player's current time is equal to the player's duration
    if CMTimeCompare(playerItem.currentTime(), playerItem.duration) == 0 {
        
        // show spinner or better yet remove spinner and show a replayButton or auto rewind to the beginning ***BE SURE TO RESET playerTryCount = 0 ***
        
    } else if playerTryCount > playerTryCountMaxLimit {
        
        // show spinner, show alert, or possibly use player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem) to start over ***BE SURE TO RESET playerTryCount = 0 ***
        print("2.-----> PROBLEM")

    } else if playerTryCount == 0 {

        // *** in his answer he has nothing but a return statement here but when it would hit this condition nothing would happen. I had to add these 2 lines of code for it to continue ***
        playerTryCount += 1
        retryCheckPlayerTryCountAgain()
        return // protects against a race condition
        
    } else if playerItem.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp {
        
        // remove spinner and reset playerTryCount to zero
        playerTryCount = 0
        player?.play()

    } else { // still hanging, not at end
        
        playerTryCount += 1
        
        /*
          create a 0.5-second delay using .asyncAfter to see if buffering catches up
          then call retryCheckPlayerTryCountAgain() in a manner that attempts to avoid any recursion or threading nightmares
        */

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in

                // test playerTryCount again to protect against changes that might have happened during the 0.5 second delay
                if self!.playerTryCount > 0 {
                    
                    if self!.playerTryCount <= self!.playerTryCountMaxLimit {
                        
                      self!.retryCheckPlayerTryCountAgain()
                        
                    } else {
                        
                      // show spinner, show alert, or possibly use player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem) to start over ***BE SURE TO RESET playerTryCount = 0 ***
                      print("3.-----> PROBLEM")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func retryCheckPlayerTryCountAgain() {
    checkPlayerTryCount()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in very bad network `playbackLikelyToKeepUp` most probably to be false.

use `kvo` to observe `playbackBufferEmpty` is better, more sensitive to if existing buffer data that can be used for playback .if the value change to true you can call play method to continue playback.

Comment: I think you are right, i think KVO's on both `playbackLikelyToKeepUp` and `playbackBufferEmpty` is required. Apple says - "**It is possible for playbackLikelyToKeepUp to indicate NO while the property playbackBufferFull indicates YES. In this event the playback buffer has reached capacity but there isn't the statistical data to support a prediction that playback is likely to keep up in the future. It is up to you to decide whether to continue media playback.**"

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

- I was trying to record video with imagePickerController and playback recorded video with AVPlayerController.  But it starts playing video and gets stops after 1 second. Somehow it gets time to save video and if you playback it immediately, it won't play.
  So solution is ,
- call play video after 0.5 seconds (delay). like below

  ```
      -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
               didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
              [self performSelector:@selector(playVideo) withObject:self 
              afterDelay:0.5];
        }


  -(void) playVideo {

     self.avPlayerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
        if(self.avPlayerViewController != nil)
      {
       AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:Vpath];
       AVPlayer* player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
       self.avPlayerViewController.player = player;
       self.avPlayerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = NO;
       [self.avPlayerViewController setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
       [self.avPlayerViewController.view setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
       self.avPlayerViewController.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
       self.avPlayerViewController.delegate = self;
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerDidFinishPlaying) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:playerItem];
       [self.viewVideoHolder addSubview:self.avPlayerViewController.view];
       [self.avPlayerViewController.player play];

   }
  ```

  }

  ```
   -(void) playerDidFinishPlaying
    {
      [avPlayer pause];
    }
  ```

[swift](/questions/tagged/swift)  [ios](/questions/tagged/ios)