# Handling AVPlayer stalls

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, key-value-observing

I'm trying to catch a moment when `AVPlayer` is unable to continue playback in case no more media available (too slow network, signal loss, etc). As described in documentation and different examples I'm using `KVO` to detect this:

```
item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:audioURL];
player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onItemNotification:) name:AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification object:item];
[item addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
[item addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

...

- (void) onItemNotification:(NSNotification*)not
{
    NSLog(@"Item notification: %@", not.name);
}

...

- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary*)change context:(void*)context
{
    NSLog(@"Observe keyPath %@", keyPath);
}
```

I'm starting a playback and turn `WiFi` off after that. Unfortunately neither '`playbackBufferEmpty`' nor '`AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification`' comes. At the moment when playback stops I receive only one `AVPlayerItemTimeJumpedNotification` and that's all.
However there were at least 2 times when I got these notifications. But I can't figure out how to get them every time when playback is stalled.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try to disconnect internet from your router and you will get playbackBufferEmpty notification. 
To handle network switching you will need to implemented [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Reachability and the playback stalls seams two different things.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 cases where player can get stuck: it never starts or it runs out of buffered data. I use the following to handle both cases:

When you create a AVPlayer instance:

```
[_player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rate" options:0 context:nil];
[_player.currentItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
```

This is the handler:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath
                     ofObject:(id)object
                       change:(NSDictionary*)change
                      context:(void*)context {

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (_player.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            //Failed to start.
            //Description from the docs:
            //  Indicates that the player can no longer play AVPlayerItem instances because of an error. The error is described by
            //  the value of the player's error property.
        }
    } else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"rate"]) {
        if (_player.rate == 0 && //playback rate is 0
                CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE(_player.currentItem.currentTime, >, kCMTimeZero) && //video has started
                CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE(_player.currentItem.currentTime, <, _player.currentItem.duration) && //video hasn't reached the end
                _isPlaying) { //instance variable to track playback state
            //Video stalled. Possible connection loss or connection is too slow.
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to remove observers when you are done:

```
[_player.currentItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
[_player removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rate"];
```

See my answer here to see how I handle stalled video: [AVPlayer stops playing and doesn't resume again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291636/avplayer-stops-playing-and-dont-resume-again/38726785#38726785)

Comment: How do you get the ‘_isPlaying’ ？