# AudioPlayer library stops playing stream .mp3

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, audio-player

I am using the library [AudioPlayer](https://github.com/delannoyk/AudioPlayer) as the Player for my app which should play an .mp3 file from a URL. The problem is that it starts playing but after a few seconds it stops and does´t continue by its own.

```
// I have set the Delegate on the VC
class SearchViewController: AudioPlayerDelegate{

// I have instantiated the AudioPlayer
let player = AudioPlayer()

// Set its delegate and some parameter so that it resumes in case of pause(declared in the viewDidLoad)
player.delegate = self
        player.resumeAfterInterruption = true
        player.resumeAfterConnectionLoss = true

// Function to check and print when stateChanges
func audioPlayer(audioPlayer: AudioPlayer, didChangeStateFrom from: AudioPlayerState, toState to: AudioPlayerState) {
        print("State changed from:\(from)to\(to)")
    }

// And a function to start Playing
func play(Link: String) {
        let item = AudioItem(highQualitySoundURL: NSURL(string: Link))
        player.playItem(item!)
    }
```

The code above is the basic. When the player stops after a few seconds this is what the didChangeStateFrom function prints. But it never starts playing again:

```
State changed from:BufferingtoPlaying
State changed from:PlayingtoBuffering
State changed from:BufferingtoPlaying
State changed from:PlayingtoBuffering
State changed from:BufferingtoPlaying
State changed from:PlayingtoBuffering
State changed from:BufferingtoPlaying
State changed from:PlayingtoBuffering
State changed from:BufferingtoPlaying
State changed from:PlayingtoBuffering
State changed from:BufferingtoPlaying
State changed from:PlayingtoBuffering
State changed from:BufferingtoPlaying
State changed from:PlayingtoBuffering
```

This is the .MP3 that I´m trying to play: http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/get/?i=CdkH4Zt%2BKY32jhzw%2FU6WmvCKfOcHPlgM%2FwDF18DRiW37FTfLBnZGRc8Z1vd5HY28rX1G3pWVrd5p9IYX%2Fvb%2B6A%3D%3D

Comment: i think this link will help you although its in obj-c: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291636/avplayer-stops-playing-and-doesnt-resume-again

Comment: @iAmd, Hello. I had seen that before and implemented it. But still I had the same issue. So I tried using this library I found on Github. And same problem too. Thanks!

Comment: what happens when you play mp3s with different URLs?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman, They seem to play fine. But I tried playing that same URL in iTunes and it did play completely fine. So this is driving me crazy :(

Comment: Have you tried it with a plain old `AVPlayer`?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman, Yes AVPlayer, and MPKitMediaPlayer had same issue with both. That´s why then I switched to this library and same happened.

Comment: Are you sure that the above is the correct URL? It points to a webpage rather than a URL.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman. Yes it is. If you paste it in iTunes you will see it plays fine. Thanks!

Comment: iTunes can play streams, perhaps it isn't a real mp3