# notification when AVPlayerItem is not stalled

Tags: ios, avfoundation

[There](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification.name/1387661-avplayeritemplaybackstalled) is a notification for when the player has stalled, called `AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled`, but there doesn't seem to be one for when the video is playing again. What's a good way to know that the video has unstalled? I could look for when the player current time changes but that sounds not great...

Comment: did you find an answer for this?

Comment: I don't think I did

Comment: There isn’t one. I did a bunch of research and came up with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62512592/4833705