# How to handle AVPlayer .AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled Notification

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, nsnotificationcenter

I'm using AVPlayer and sometimes the player randomly pauses. I'm observing `\.timeControlStatus` but the only response I get `.paused`. I'm also observing `\.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp`, `\.isPlaybackBufferEmpty`, and `\.isPlaybackBufferFull` but nothing fires for those. However using `Notification.Name.AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled` I do get a print statement that says "stalled".

Even though `\.rate` fires when the the player pauses, that fires before `.AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled` fires, sometimes `\.timeControlStatus .paused` fires after `.AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled` and the player just sits there.

What should I do once `.AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled` runs and the player is sitting paused?

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerItemPlaybackStalled(_:)),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled,
                                               object: playerItem)

@objc fileprivate func playerItemPlaybackStalled(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("playerItemPlaybackStalled")
}
```

Here is my full code:

```
let player = AVPlayer()
player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
// add KVO observers and NotificationCenter observers
// playerItem keys are already loaded
playerItem.preferredForwardBufferDuration = TimeInterval(1.0)
player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)


playerStatusObserver = player?.observe(\.currentItem?.status, options: [.new, .old]) { [weak self] (player, change) in
        
    switch (player.status) {
    case .readyToPlay:
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // play video
        }
    case .failed, .unknown:
        print("Video Failed to Play")
    @unknown default:
        break
    }
}
    
playerRateObserver = player?.observe(\.rate, options:  [.new, .old], changeHandler: { [weak self](player, change) in

    if player.rate == 1  {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // if player isn't playing play it
        }
    } else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           // is player is playing pause it
        }
    }
})
    
playerTimeControlStatusObserver = player?.observe(\.timeControlStatus, options: [.new, .old]) { [weak self](player, change) in
        
    switch (player.timeControlStatus) {
    case .playing:
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                // if player isn't playing pay it
            }
    case .paused:
            print("timeControlStatus is paused") // *** SOMETIMES PRINTS after .AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled runs***

    case .waitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate:
            print("timeControlStatus- .waitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate")

    if let reason = player.reasonForWaitingToPlay {
                
            switch reason {
            case .evaluatingBufferingRate:
                    print("timeControlStatus- .evaluatingBufferingRate") // never prints
                    
            case .toMinimizeStalls:
                    print("timeControlStatus- .toMinimizeStalls") // never prints
                    
            case .noItemToPlay:
                    print("timeControlStatus- .noItemToPlay") // never prints
                    
            default:
                    print("Unknown \(reason)")
            }
        }
    @unknown default:
        break
    }
}
    
playbackLikelyToKeepUpObserver = player?.currentItem?.observe(\.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp, options: [.old, .new]) {  (playerItem, change) in
    print("isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp") // never prints
}
    
playbackBufferEmptyObserver = player?.currentItem?.observe(\.isPlaybackBufferEmpty, options: [.old, .new]) { (playerItem, change) in
    print("isPlaybackBufferEmpty") // never prints
}
    
playbackBufferFullObserver = player?.currentItem?.observe(\.isPlaybackBufferFull, options: [.old, .new]) { (playerItem, change) in
    print("isPlaybackBufferFull") // never prints
}
    
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerItemDidReachEnd(_:)),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                               object: playerItem)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime(_:)),
                                           name: .AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime,
                                           object: playerItem)
    
    
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerItemNewError(_:)),
                                           name: .AVPlayerItemNewErrorLogEntry,
                                           object: playerItem)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerItemPlaybackStalled(_:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled,
                                           object: playerItem)

@objc func playerItemDidReachEnd(_ notification: Notification) {
    // show replay button
}

@objc func playerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("playerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime") // never prints

    if let error = notification.userInfo?["AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime"] as? Error {
        print(error.localizedDescription) // never prints
    }
}

@objc func playerItemNewError(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("playerItemNewErrorLogEntry") // never prints
}

@objc func playerItemPlaybackStalled(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("playerItemPlaybackStalled") // *** PRINTS ***
}
```

Comment: @matt btw thanks for the advice, I'll put up an activity indicator and won't touch the player.

Comment: @matt it keeps happening and the problem is nothing occurs afterwards meaning none of the other observers or notifications get called. The video is only 15 secs, it froze after 5 secs or so, I let it sit for 5 minutes expecting something to happen but nada. If it's trying to fill the buffer shouldn't it have been filled within that 5 min period and one of the other methods fired off?

Comment: Well, I guess I'm wrong. I don't know why the video would stall after just five seconds, more info is probably needed.

Comment: Also I don't quite get why you're setting `automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling` to `false`, this sort of defeats the purpose.

Comment: I added **automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false** thinking maybe it'll help it play faster. What do you mean it defeats the purpose? I'll comment it out to see if the stall still occurs

Comment: I just commented it out, the stall still occurs

Comment: Yeah, weird. The idea of automatically waiting is that we fill the buffer up front, I think. But clearly there's some other issue. As I said, it sounds like more info is needed.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll keep playing around with it to see if I can find something out. I have question about something from your iOS 10 book: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62489214/4833705

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62512592/4833705). Basically inside the stalled notification I check to see if the buffer is full or not. If not I run the code from the link.